# when I click on Expand all div are expanded

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.text-hidden').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

This is the code click on expand div expand but why all the div having class text-hidden expand and how to use this keyword for text-hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but why all the div having class text-hidden expand...

Because that's what `$('.text-hidden').slideToggle();` says to do: Find all elements with the class `text-hidden` and call `slideToggle` on them.

If you just want the ones within the div that was clicked, you have to tell jQuery that, for instance with the [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).find(".text-hidden").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).find(".text-hidden").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.text-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
    <div>Always visible</div>
    <div class="text-hidden">Hidden by default</div>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
    <div>Always visible</div>
    <div class="text-hidden">Hidden by default</div>
</div>

<div class="toggle">
    <div>Always visible</div>
    <div class="text-hidden">Hidden by default</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if both `.toggle` and `.text-hidden` elements are in the same container, you might need to go up to that container first (via [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)); in this example, I'll use the class `container` as a stand-in for whatever identifies the common container:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".container").find(".text-hidden").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".container").find(".text-hidden").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.text-hidden {
    display: none;
}
.toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Always visible (<a class="toggle">toggle hidden</a>)</div>
    <div class="text-hidden">Hidden by default</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div>Always visible (<a class="toggle">toggle hidden</a>)</div>
    <div class="text-hidden">Hidden by default</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div>Always visible (<a class="toggle">toggle hidden</a>)</div>
    <div class="text-hidden">Hidden by default</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```